# Get selected option text in ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I use ractive.js to bind a selectbox. I should submit the id of option to server, so I use id and name. But for displaying, I should show the text of option.

```
<select value='{{selectedCountry}}'>
    {{#countries}}
        <option value='{{id}}'>{{name}}</option>
    {{/countries}}
</select>

ractive = new Ractive({
    el: myContainer,
    template: myTemplate,
    data: {
        countries: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Afghanistan' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Albania' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Algeria' }
        ]
    }
});
```

But I only can get the id, how to get the text in option?

```
<div>
{{selectedCountry}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use the country object itself for binding:

```js
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    countries: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Afghanistan' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Albania' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Algeria' }
    ]
  }
});

ractive.observe( 'selectedCountry', function ( country ) {
  console.log( 'saving %s to server', country.id );
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  <select value='{{selectedCountry}}'>
    {{#countries}}
      <option value='{{this}}'>{{name}}</option>
    {{/countries}}
  </select>
  
  <p>selected country:
    {{selectedCountry.id}}/{{selectedCountry.name}}
  </p>
</script>

<main></main>
```

The alternative would be to find the relevant item using something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s `findWhere` method:

```
ractive.observe( 'selectedCountry', function ( id ) {
  var country = _.findWhere( this.get( 'countries' ),  { id: id });
  this.set( 'selectedCountryName', country.name );
});
```

Obviously that's more code to type, and less efficient (since you need to do the lookup each time), so I'd recommend doing it the first way.

Comment: It works, how about if I bind a simple array? `countries: ['Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria']`. I just tried, but I can get the value only when I use `{{this}}`, can I get the index?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can make it work with a simple array:

```js
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    countries: ['Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria']
  }
});

ractive.observe( 'selectedCountryId', function ( id ) {
  console.log( 'saving %s to server', id );
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  <select value='{{selectedCountryId}}'>
    {{#countries:i}} <!-- add a semicolon and an identifier to use index during iteration -->
      <option value='{{i+1}}'>{{this}}</option>
    {{/countries}}
  </select>
  
  <p>selected country: {{selectedCountryId}}/{{countries[selectedCountryId-1]}}
  </p>
</script>

<main></main>
```